# SQL Server 2017 Installation issue on window 7

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am facing problem installing SQL Server 2017 (Developer as well as Express editions).

I get an error:

> Your operating system is not supported by SQL Server 2017

My system configuration is:

- Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1
- 8 GB RAM, 64 bit OS, processor: 2.3 GHz

What is issue with my OS, what to do to install it?

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server 2017 does not support Windows 7, you need at least Windows 8. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this message on 32 Bit Windows 10

"Installation of SQL Server is supported on x64 processors only. It is no longer supported on x86 processors."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I could only get SQL Server 2014 installed on Windows 10 32 bit edition.

Answer (score 0):

> what to do to install it?

Probably install virtual box and use Linux version.

At least you will not need license for OS.